# Why does the title attribute have a delay?

Tags: usability, html, tooltips

In HTML the [`title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#title) attribute usually displays a little popup conveying information about the element. In most—if not all—browsers the popup doesn't appear immediately but after few seconds.

**Why was it decided that there should be a delay and how long that delay should be?**

What benefits are there to the user with there being a delay and the tooltip not appearing immediately after hover?

Comment: I don't believe this question has anything to do with user experience, unless you're asking if that delay is good to the user and how it affects them?

Comment: I think that the delay is intentional, so why did they put it? Is it improving the UX?

Comment: You should probably revise your question, because it appears as though you're asking how it works, as apposed to how it affects the end user.

Comment: Because if you are asking how it works, then you should post this question in www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Majed the question is why not how. if it was how then it could go on stackoverflow. this is definitely a ux question imo

Comment: @BennySkogberg I want to know why there's a delay and I'm sure it's not because of a programming issue but it's an UX decision. I want to know the reason behind that decision.

Comment: the length of delay after hovering over an element with a title attribute was decided by a UX designer not a programmer. this is ux.

Comment: Very closely related to (if not a duplicate) of [How long should the delay be before a tooltip pops up?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/358/how-long-should-the-delay-be-before-a-tooltip-pops-up)

Comment: @Gpx I've retracted the close vote since I think your correct in a way. Still it's almost a duplicate of Matts posted question.

Comment: He updated his question. Initially it was phrased in a way where it sounded like he was curious, through either code or technicality, why it was taking so long to render. Now it reads like a UX question ;-)

Comment: Can I make it have no delay on my website?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Without a delay just moving your mouse around would accidentally make popups appear and flicker across your screen.

That'd draw users' attention away from what they're doing if they didn't expect it, and probably annoy them because flickering stuff provides no value to them: it's unlikely they wanted to read the title and unlikely they even have the time to do it.